# What exactly is being measured by "Process Memory" in Visual Studio (2022)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I'm debugging an ASP.NET Core application running on NET 6.0. It's exhibiting a memory leak, and when I look in the diagnostics window, I see something like this:

[image]

When I was taking snapshots, I noticed that as I ran my application and sent HTTP requests to it, both the "Process Memory" indicator, and the Objects / Heap Size in the Heap Snapshots were increasing. After some more debugging, I discovered that disabling Microsoft's App Insights and the `MemoryCache` caused the growth in the **managed heap** to stop, and remain in a quiescent level. However, the Process Memory measurement still keeps growing.

What exactly is being measured by "Process Memory" in this view? And if my managed memory consumption isn't growing anymore, why is this "Process Memory" value still growing?